# Algorithm for determining if 2 graphs are isomorphic

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, graph, graph-theory

Disclaimer: I'm a total newbie at graph theory and I'm not sure if this belongs on SO, Math SE, etc.

Given 2 adjacency matrices A and B, how can I determine if A and B are isomorphic.

For example, A and B which are not isomorphic and C and D which are isomorphic.

```
A = [ 0 1 0 0 1 1     B = [ 0 1 1 0 0 0
      1 0 1 0 0 1           1 0 1 1 0 0
      0 1 0 1 0 0           1 1 0 1 1 0
      0 0 1 0 1 0           0 1 1 0 0 1
      1 0 0 1 0 1           0 0 1 0 0 1
      1 1 0 0 1 0 ]         0 0 0 1 1 0 ]

C = [ 0 1 0 1 0 1     D = [ 0 1 0 1 1 0
      1 0 1 0 0 1           1 0 1 0 1 0
      0 1 0 1 1 0           0 1 0 1 0 1
      1 0 1 0 1 0           1 0 1 0 0 1
      0 0 1 1 0 1           1 1 0 0 0 1
      1 1 0 0 1 0 ]         0 0 1 1 1 0 ]   

(sorry for this ugly notation, I'm not quite sure how to draw matrices on SO)
```

Here's how I've started my algorithm (pardon my lack of mathematical rigor) please help me complete/correct!

1. If size (number of edges, in this case amount of 1s) of A != size of B => graphs are not isomorphic
2. For each vertex of A, count its degree and look for a matching vertex in B which has the same degree *and* was not matched earlier. If there is no match => graphs are not isomorphic.
3. Now that we cannot quickly prove that A and B are not isomorphic, what's the next step?
   Would it be correct try every permutation of lines in A until A matches B? Really not sure about this one...

Comment: I'm sure it's terrible, but you could always brute force it: keep the nodes in A in order, then go through every permutation of the labeling of nodes in B until they match or there are no more. Of course, there's almost certainly a better way... [like this...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism#Recognition_of_graph_isomorphism seems that no-one knows any polynomial time algorithm. So it's  ok to just brute-force. try every permutation of nodes of same degree etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's a quite difficult problem to solve. There is a Wikipedia page about it:

- [Graph isomorphism problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem)

According to that page there are a number of special cases that have been solved with efficient polynomial time solutions, but the complexity of the optimal solution is still unknown.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Strangely enough, I have an intuition that graph isomorphism should be an easy problem to solve since it seems quite easy for my brain to visually determine if 2 graphs are isomorph. Maybe I haven't tried on a big enough graph...

Comment: Haha, I have the exact opposite problem. Can't see if two graphs are isomorphic even if they are very small.

Comment: @olivier Lalonde: How long does your brain take to check for isomorphism in dense graphs with 50, 100 or more nodes?

Answer (score 6):

My project - Griso - at sf.net: http://sourceforge.net/projects/griso/ with this description:
Griso is a graph isomorphism testing utility written in C++ and based on my own algo.
See Griso's sample input/output on this page: http://funkybee.narod.ru/graphs.htm

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is very easy to quickly tell that they ARE NOT isomorphic by doing the following.

`areIsomorphic(G1, G2):
      if(G1.num_verticies != G2.num_verticies)
              return False
       if(G1.num_total_edges != G2.num_total_edges)
              return False
      for each vertex v in G1:
            if( G2.find(v).edges != v.edges):
                     return False;
        //Try and find a property in graph G1 that does not exist in G2.
        // Use a heuristic. ie- try and find nonmutually adjacenct sets.`

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is not a simple task to prove that two graphs are isomorphic. For that reason we must consider some properties of isomorphic graphs. That means those properties must be satisfied if the graphs are isomorphic. If the given graph does not satisfy these properties then we can say they are not isomorphic graphs.

Property: Two graphs are isomorphic if and only if for some ordering of their vertices their adjacency matrices are equal.

Based on the above property we can decide whether the given graphs are isomorphic or not. In order to check the property, we need to do some matrix transformation operations.