# Verify a given graph to a known graph (graph isomorphism) ?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, depth-first-search

I am representing chemicals with graphs.

Suppose we have a graph G' and we want to verify that it matches the graph G. The graphs have a 'type' property (the type of atom) for each vertex, which must also match. The edges also have an integer value (the number of bonds between atoms) that must also match between graphs G and G'.

Suppose both graphs have a source vertex s where the algorithm can start. If a good solution would employ a depth-first search, for example, it should start from the vertex s.

The graphs will have cycles, which complicates the algorithm. Anyone have any ideas on how to do this efficiently?

Comment: You can conduct the DFS simultaneously in the two graphs with marking each node traversed as visited so that it does not get repeated.

Comment: I am not sure I see how that would verify the two graphs are the same?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you can start with the source nodes of both graphs, iterate through them simultaneously, and keep comparing whether all their respective nodes and edges have the same value / type.

Comment: Yeah, the thing is though that DFS is some-what arbitrary. If each DFS takes a different path then the comparison becomes difficult.

Comment: you should take indentical paths for the DFS. It is very easy if the graphs are the same. The point where they do not match, you can exit the DFS with false condition.

Comment: I see. What should I base the pathing on? The degree/type of the neighbors and the integer values of the edges? What if both neighbors are identical in these values ?

Comment: A DFS chooses any of the outgoing edge (in your case choose the same edge in both graphs) and goes deep into it, while pushing its neighbours in a stack in any order (in your case, the same order for both graphs).

Comment: But how will it know that the neighbors are the same before it chooses to traverse through them?

Comment: Please show your graph implementation.

Comment: Will the graphs always be planar?

Comment: I haven't implemented the graphs yet. I suppose they will be adjacency lists. 

Graphs will always be planar.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Algorithm for determining if 2 graphs are isomorphic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876354/algorithm-for-determining-if-2-graphs-are-isomorphic)